# Different Spring config files for different builds

Tags: java, spring, ant, build, config

In Spring application, I set up app-security.xml to controll all the security issues. However, the production will use SSO, where as on local machine I would like the plain old user authentification. I also have two local machines - for one, the project is built by IntelliJ Idea, and for another - by Ant, producing a WAR. Production system will be built using Ant.

How do I organize my project so it would be possible to develop conveniently and also be able to build a production-like system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) bean to define variables for you. You can try

```
<import resource="${resource}" />
```

The `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` bean scans the xml configuration for variables such as `${resource}` and replace those based on settings from a property file. This assumes you have separate values in your property file for production and development.

A tip for future project would be to try `maven` out. There is a `filtering` feature there which allows you to define custom properties based on profiles, very neat and useful.

Comment: Rather than Maven profiles it might be easier to treat each environment as a different artifact. That way you don't have to remember special command line flags.

Comment: Not a bad idea, personally I let my IDE figure those out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I used this approach recently to solve similar issue. I used new feature of Spring 3 - expression language. It allows you to to do something like this:

```
<bean class="com.my.AuthManager">
    <property name="authProvider" 
              ref="#{systemProperties['isDevelopment'] ? 'localProvider' : 'ssoProvider'}" />
</bean>

<bean id="localProvider" lazy-init="true" ... />
<bean id="ssoProvider" lazy-init="true" ... />
```

In this case you can start JVM with `-DisDevelopment=true` and `localProvider` would be used. From other hand, `ssoProvider` would not be even instantiated because `lazy-init` attribute is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property file to customize for different environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move to Spring 3.1 then it has native support for environment specific profiles

> 'Environment Profiles' will allow for
>   placeholder resolution based on a
>   specified environment name (or names).
>   This allows different configuration
>   in, for example, dev and production,
>   without having two different
>   deployment artifacts. I think he also
>   mentioned an Environment abstraction,
>   which I assume would be for accessing
>   the same configuration
>   programatically.

If you are on older versions then you might want to manage this your self (mainly through build process. we are using maven and we use maven profiles to do this. I believe you can do the same with ant as well). Here is one discussion on this: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=12373

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Configleon](http://code.google.com/p/configleon/) in my latest Spring based project to have properties file loaded by Spring based on the environment I'm in.
The library works for both web application and applications not using Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like to have different WAR files for each environment.   It's a big DRY violation.   Spring 3.1 will finally address this issue in the core.   In the meantime you can either use the Spring EL approach as given by Easy Angel, or (my preference) use a @Bean with code to switch between the different implementations.

Comment: Video talking about what's coming in 3.1 relating to this question: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Configuration-in-Spring-3-1